# Translating "fake news" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

For this *trending* modern (or rather contemporary idiom), I have two possible translations, but am not sure which one better suits the specificity of Latin:

> 1. **audītiōnēs falsae** (or *falsae audītiōnēs*)
> 2. **audītiōnēs fallāciloquae** (or *fallāciloquae audītiōnēs*)

While **1.** seems to be the more straightforward and obvious solution, **2.**, on the other hand, appears to be more subtly in tune with what *fake news* actually means as the adjective [**fallāciloquus, fallāciloqua, fallāciloquum**](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1006076) actually means "speaking deceitfully, false."

Comment: See also: [Quomodo in Latinum vertitur “alternative facts”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2465/118)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is ***nuntii fallaces***.

I might be biased as a Finn, but I'm used to *nuntii* as the typical translation of "news".
It has a nuance of a delivered message, whereas *auditio(nes)* sounds more like a rumor.
It is up to you to choose which one is more suitable in any given situation.
I would say that using the word *auditio* already has a mocking tone when referring to news, but perhaps others will disagree.

If the news are wrong, then I'd call them *falsi*.
If they speak deceitfully, I might indeed call them *fallaciloqui*, but it strikes me a little odd to use such an adjective for news.
It depends on what you refer to with the word "news".
If you mean a "news broadcast on TV", then speaking deceitfully is a good pick.
But if you mean news in some other media or news as a "collection of news items" (instead of the broadcast that delivers them), I would use the adjective *fallax* instead.

The adjective you suggest is combined from *fallax* and *loqui*.
The word *fallax* on its own means "deceitful" or "fallacious".
*Fallax* means someone who tends to *fallere*; this is what the *-ax* suffix does.

In conclusion, the nouns *nuntii* and *auditio(nes)* are both possible, and so are the adjectives *falsus*, *fallaciloquus* and *fallax*.
It depends on what you want to convey exactly.
But I think *nuntii fallaces* is the most appropriate choice for "fake news" the way I understand the English term.

Answer (score 4):

Joonas's answer is excellent, but for the sake of multiple viewpoints here's how I would translate the term.

Rather than a noun+adjective, as you suggest, I would use a substantive. As [another recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/about-joyful-news) brought up, the adjective "gladdening" means "good news" when used as a neuter plural substantive, literally "gladdening things". And the word "news" itself originated as a plural substantive.

*Fallāciloquus* is an excellent adjective, with a nicely derogatory tone. So I would translate "fake news" as ***fallāciloqua***, "[things] speaking falsely".

As a bonus, this translation can be used as an adjective, as in "the mainstream fake-news media".